# How to overload a function with different argument list and avoid code duplication？

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates

I want to overload a function with different argument list.

For example, the declaration look like this:

```
void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData)
void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData, const std::vector<int>& edgeData)
```

In the application, some graphs have edge data, while some do not.

This function will iterate over vertex and edge data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vnum; ++i) { 
for (int j = idx[i]; j < idx[i+1]; ++j) {
    int dst = edge[j]
    vertexData[i] = vertexData[i] + 1; // update vertex
    edgeData[j] = edgeData[j] + 1; // update edge
}
}
```

I have to duplicate the code in two functions, and they only differ in one line-the update edge line.

Currently I am using macro to avoid duplication.

I will not overload the function.

```
void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData
#ifdef PROCESSEDGE
, const std::vector<int>& edgeData
#endif
)
```

And in the definition

```
// inside some for loop
vertexData[i] = j; // update vertex
#ifdef PROCESSEDGE
edgeData[k] = l; // update edge
#endif
```

For different configurations, I add the `PROCESSEDGE` macro.

It is obvious that this has no overhead. But it is not elegant.

Another idea that came to my mind is to use some compile time conditions in c++11.

The declaration looks like this

```
void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData, const std::vector<EdgeType>& edgeData)
```

The implementation is

```
// inside some for loop
vertexData[i] = j; // update vertex
if (!std::is_same<Empty, EdgeData>::value)
edgeData[k] = l; // update edge
```

Because the condition is evaluated at compile time, it is supposed to have no runtime overhead. But the if statement is not elegant as well, as far as I am concerned.

What is the best practise to do this elegantly?

[UPDATE] I want everything to be done statically.

Comment: Have one call the other, or make a third function they both call.

Comment: I'm not seeing what's wrong with a default argument of an empty edge vector or a delegating call with an empty edge vector.

Comment: In `void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData)` why don't you just have the line `processGraph(vertexData, std::vector<EdgeType>())` and then all the code is in the other function except the edge vector is empty so you know there are no edges.

Comment: Actually the idea of @chris is good: use a default argument value.  You don't even need two functions.

Comment: If I add empty as defautl argument, I have to modify the implementation: check the vector at runtime.

Comment: It will be helpful to see the entire function to suggest the best way to refactor it.

Comment: hi @EJP I cannot do it because the processGraph code is very complicated. I know it is not good to put too many things in the same function. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I'm really confused what `k` is if that edge line is the only change. A [mcve] would be great for helping us to understand the problem and give a proper solution. It should be possible to create a simple function based on the same principle as the one you have, where you can apply the solution back to the real code.

Comment: hi @chris Thanks for your instruction. I have updated the example.

Comment: @youwei That's exactly *why* you *should* do it. Move the complex code to a third function for example and arrange two wrappers for it. Or use default arguments as suggested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:  Provide bogus edge data that the implementation you delegate to can scribble on, then drop it on the floor.  This adds some memory requirements, but the assignments in the loop are trivial and there's no branching added to the loop.

```
void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData) {
    std::vector<int> dummyEdgeData;
    dummyEdgeData.resize(/* some appropriate value */);
    processGraph(vetexData, dummyEdgeData);
}

void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData, const std::vector<int>& edgeData) {
    // inside some for loop
    vertexData[i] = j; // update vertex
    edgeData[k] = l; // update edge
}
```

Option 2:  Have faith that a branch inside the loop will be predicted well in the case there is no edge data.

Option 3:  Use a functor (like a lambda) to handle the assignments and provide the "right" one, just like `std::for_each` lets you provide the body of a loop.

```
template <typename Functor>
void processGraphLoop(Functor f) {
    // inside some for loop
    f(i, j, k, l);
}

void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData) {
    processGraphLoop([&](int i, int j, int k, int l) {
                         vertexData[i] = j;
                     });
}

void processGraph(const std::vector<int>& vertexData, const std::vector<int>& edgeData) {
    processGraphLoop([&](int i, int j, int k, int l) {
                         vertexData[i] = j;
                         edgeData[k] = l;
                     });
}
```